# Prove that $d(f,Y) \lt 1,$ for any $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X = \left \{f \in C[0,1]\ \big |\ f(0) = 0 \right \}$ and $Y = \left \{f \in X\ \bigg |\ \displaystyle {\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = 0} \right \}.$ Show that there does not exist any $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$ such that $d \left (f,Y \right ) \geq 1.$

If for any $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$ we can able to find $g_f \in Y$ such that $\left \|f - g_f \right \|_{\infty} \lt 1$ then we are through. But for a given $f \in X$ how to find such a $g_f\ $? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon here $d(f,Y)= \inf\limits_{g \in Y} \|f - g\|_{\infty}.$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Such $g_f$ does not necesarily belong to $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$. Consider $C = \int_{0}^1 f(t)dt$.  Why is $|C|<1$? (The sign is strict)

Now find a $f' \in X$ such that $\int_0^t f' > C$ and $\|f'\|_{\infty} = 1$ (use a function that goes from $0$ to $1$ very fast, then stays at $1$, so the integral goes above $C$) and let $h = f - \frac{cf'}{\int_0^1 f'(x)dx}$. Then see that $\|f-h\|_{\infty}< 1$.